# how to use html select multiple tag?

Tags: php, html, multipleselection

I want to use HTML select multiple tag to enable users to select more than one options. The HTML code is as written below:

```
<select name="students" multiple>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

Now what I want is to get all the selected values and use them in a php code. When I print the POSTed data it shows only the value of last option selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your select tag array name: `students[]` instead of `students`, otherwise it will not be array and will always contain last selected element, as last one overwrites previous.

so `[]` gives elements ability to hold multiple items

```
<select name="students[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Can you provide a link that document this "[]" trick ?
(Obviously) it is a PHP thing (I don't know PHP).
HTML send (as expected) all the selected values in the HTTP POST form elements collection without the need to change anything.
I think that this point (it is a PHP trick) should be evidenced clearly (if I'm right).

Comment: Hi @Alex75 no it's html thing, just lets u send an array of input data under same name, to make it easier for server side processing.

Answer (score -1):

In php , read them as

```
foreach($_POST['students'] as $value)
 {
 // your code  // e.g. echo $val;
 }
```

Comment: its not possible. $_POST['students'] is not an array type